# Angles of Intersection between Two Curves

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I was looking for the angle of intersection between the two curves $y = ln x$ and $y = ln (1-x)$

My work:

First: I need to find the point of intersection between the two curves. I found the point $(1, ln 0.5)$ to be its intersection.

Second: I need to find the angle of intersection between two curves. Its angle would be: $$tan \theta = \frac{m_1 - m_2}{1+m_1 m_2}$$

So, I gotta find $m_1$ and $m_2$

Looking for $m_1:$
$$y = ln x$$ $$y' = \frac{1}{x}$$
Then, at $x= 1$ from the point of intersection:
$$y' = 1$$

Looking for $m_2:$
$$y = ln (1-x)$$ $$y' = \frac{-1}{1-x}$$
Then, at $x= 1$ from the point of intersection:
$$y' = -infinity$$

I got $m_1$ and $m_2$, so the value of $tan \theta$ is:

$$tan \theta = \frac{1 - (-infinity)}{1+(1)(-infinity)}$$
$$tan \theta = \frac{1}{-1}$$

Finally: I got the angle between the two aforementioned curves to be $\theta = 135$ degrees.

The book I used says that the angle between two curves is $53.1$ degrees, which makes my answer wrong.

How do you get the correct answer of $53.1$ degrees?

Comment: You CAN'T do calculation with $\infty$ like this!

Comment: I don't know how you came up with your "point of intersection," but when finding an intersection it pays to check whether the result is actually on the two intersecting curves. One curve has points of the form $(x,y) = (x, \ln x)$; is $(1, \ln \frac12)$ on that curve?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The intersection point is wrong

Indeed $\log x=\log(1-x)$ means $x=1-x$ that is $x=\frac12$

$m_1=2;\;m_2=-2$

$\tan\theta=\dfrac{-2-2}{1+2(-2)}=\dfrac{4}{3}$

$\theta\approx 53.13°$

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

As was pointed out in a comment, you can't treat $\infty$ like a number in this way. However, as soon as you see $\infty$ appear in the way it did here, that should already be a red flag.

Geometrically, if the derivative of a function blows up to $\infty$ at a point, that means the tangent line at that point is vertical. (This happens, for instance, with $\sqrt[3]{x}$.) But if you look at graphs of $\ln x$ and $\ln (1-x)$, you'll see that they don't have any points where the tangent is vertical.

So this is a clue that you made a mistake in calculating either the point of intersection (as it was in this case) or the derivative.